# Is it ok to set a variable inside parentheses such as this example I have?

Tags: javascript

Was wondering if it's ok to use this syntax below where I set 'box.w' inside the parentheses. It works for me, but I wasn't sure if I should stay away from it, or if there could be compatibility issues. I'm aware I could just use an if;else block, but I liked the way this looked.

Any help || advice would be appreciated.

```
let box = {w: 0, h: 0};

getWidth = (var1, var2) => {

  let roundedX = calcRoundedDistance(var1, var2);

  roundedX && (box.w = roundedX) || (box.w = var1 - var2);

}
```

> roundedX && (**box.w = roundedX**) || (**box.w = var1 - var2**);

Comment: **Mutating by evaluating** can be really confusung and even bug prone IMHO

Comment: What's wrong with using an `if..else`…?

Comment: If I was reviewing this code on a Pull Request I would definitely ask you to change it :)

Comment: I would say it's more readable to have `box.w = roundedX || (var1 - var2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
box.w = roundedX || (var1 - var2);
```

Comment: Looks like I was just over complicating it. I guess long periods of time with no sleep can make you forget the simplest solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's hard to read and comprehend. If you don't want to if/else, [use a ternary expression instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
box.w = roundedX ? roundedX : var1 - var2;
```

Comment: how about `box.w = roundedX || (var1 - var2);`

Comment: @AkashDathan That would also work, but again, arguably harder to read.

Comment: how about `box.w = roundedX ?? (var1 - var2);`, this new operator is made specifically for this purpose, for those who don't know [`Nullish coalescing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: @jonatjano no, that is not equivalent code. `??` would create unexpected results. For example, if `roundedX` is 0, 0 actually PASSES the `??` check but it fails for `||`